# Why my angular code throw error: cannot read the property of undefined?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, angular7

I am getting data from web API which returns a JSON object, it returns fine but when I loop over that then it throws an error that Cannot read the property of undefined 'CustomerName'.

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public object GetBookings(string SearchByParam = "", byte WhichRecords 
      = 1)
    {
        List<ZahidCarWash.ViewModels.BookingArrivalCancellationViewModel> 
        lstBookingArrivalCancellation = 
      BookingsRepository.SelectCustomerBookingDetailsAndroid(SearchByParam, 
      WhichRecords);

        if (lstBookingArrivalCancellation.Count > 0)
        {
            return Json(new { ReturnStatusJSON = true, lstArrivalCancellation = lstBookingArrivalCancellation });
        }

        else
        {
            return Json(new { ReturnStatusJSON = false, lstArrivalCancellation = lstBookingArrivalCancellation });
        }
           }
```

Customer.service.ts

```
export class CustomerService {
    formData: Customer;
    Data: Customer[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData() {
        return
        this.http.get('http://localhost:13924/api/AndroidOperations/GetBookings')
            .subscribe(function(data: any) {
            this.Data = data['lstArrivalCancellation'] as Customer[];
            console.log(this.Data);
        });
    }

}
```

customer-list.component.ts

```
export class CustomersListComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public service: CustomerService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getData();
    }

}
```

.html

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
  <tr *ngFor="let d of service.Data | async"></tr>
   <td *ngIf="CustomerName">{{d.CustomerName}}</td>
   <td>Tr</td>
 </table>
```

Customer Mode:

```
   export class Customer {
     CustomerID: number ;
     CustomerName: string;
     ContactNo: string;
     VehicleRegNo: string;
     fk_VehicleMakeID: number;
     VehicleModel: number;

    }
```

Comment: first check `d ` after that `CustomerName` i.e: `ngIf="d  &&  CustomerName"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `ngIf` in the html code from

```
<td *ngIf="CustomerName">{{d.CustomerName}}</td>
```

to

```
<td *ngIf="d">{{d?.CustomerName}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for CustomerName in your *ngIf statement where you should be  checking for d.CustomerName. 'd' will always be there since you are iterating through the collection it is in. But of d.CustomerName is undefined it rails.

```
<div *ngIf="d.CustomerName">{{d.CustomerName}}</div
```

should do the trick.